# Django AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS import error

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-settings

What is the proper way to import a custom backend in settings.py? I currently have the following in settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth')
```

where apployment_site is the app, auth is file name, and CustomAuth is the class name.

In my view, I get: `ImportError: a doesn't look like a module path` after I run the following code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from apployment_site import *
authenticate(username="username", password="password")
```

Here's my full settings.py:

```
"""Django settings for apployment project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3(a=jr=tfedkqzv3f=495%0$ygxjt332(=n0&h=e2bzh(i#r*j'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apployment_site'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth')

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apployment.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'apployment.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

make sure it's a tuple:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth',)
```

note the comma at the end

Comment: This was correct, thanks! I also had to remove "apps". The correct line was AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth',)

Comment: i have this same issue but AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth',) is not working for me. it says ImportError: No module named apployment_site.auth

Comment: @Nitheesh, is your custom app's name is actually `apployment_site`, or is it something different? And does your python module `custom_app_name.auth.py` contains `CutomAuth` class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to actually import it into your `view`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends), Django will go through all your authentication backends when you call `authenticate()`.

Thus, just make sure you have all the authentication backends you want in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Right, but Django doesn't seem to like the way I'm referencing my custom backend in settings.py. Do you know what the right syntax is for it? Neither 'apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth' nor apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth'work

Comment: What's your directory structure? Where is your CustomAuth located? Also, why do you have the `from apployment_site import *` in your views code? Isn't that what's throwing the error?

Comment: Nope, that's just importing my models. The error is in my settings.py when I'm defining authentication_backend. Currently, auth is a file defined within my apployment_site app, and the main class is called CustomAuth. That's why I assumed AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth') was the right way to reference this.

Comment: Could you post your whole `settings.py` file? Weird that it's saying 'a' doesn't look like a module path.

Comment: Sure, I edited my original post to include it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in all the relevant directories? Based on your code, your project root should have a directory called 'apps' (with an __init__.py file), which should have a directory called 'apployment_site (with an __init__.py file), with a file call auth. Is that all true?