# Django: m doesn't look like a module path

Tags: python, django

I can vistit the /admin url

but went I login admin or call my login api. I got this error message

error:

```
ImportError at /admin/login/
m doesn't look like a module path
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Django Version: 1.8.17
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
m doesn't look like a module path
Exception Location: /root/.virtualenvs/areyoutired/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py in import_string, line 21
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/root/.virtualenvs/areyoutired/lib/python3.4',
 '/root/.virtualenvs/areyoutired/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/root/.virtualenvs/areyoutired/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/root/.virtualenvs/areyoutired/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Comment: I feel like the standard "don't run things like this as root" talk is in order...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't given enough details to know for certain, however I am going to guess that this is a problem with your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting. See [Django AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095951/django-authentication-backends-import-error) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 19):

the problem is

my settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'member.backends.EmailPasswordBackend'
)
```

does not have "," behind 'member.backends.EmailPasswordBackend'

so i got "m doesn't look like a module path"

that's so shame on me

Comment: To simplify, after 'member.backends.EmailPasswordBackend' add a comma like this 'member.backends.EmailPasswordBackend',

Answer (score 1):

put `mysite.DemoRouter.DemoRouter` if `Demorouter` is the class which is in folder `mysite`

Answer (score 0):

If you have given any backend such as `EMAIL_BACKEND, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS etc` to an empty string like `EMAIL_BACKEND = ""` will throw this error.

Just change it to `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`
 or the right backend of your choice.

Here you need to provide right AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

Answer (score 0):

should be described with a comma.

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'),)

I had the same error due to a comma miss